# node.js stream header range is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am creating a streaming module that will stream *any* file on my server to the user

for this i have the following node code:

```
    .get(function (req, res) {
        if (req.query.resourceToken) {
        var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.resourceToken, require('../secret')());
        var mediaObject = decoded.mediaObject;
        var file = path.resolve(mediaObject.targetDir, mediaObject.file.originalname);
        fs.stat(file, function (err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                    // 404 Error if file not found
                    return res.sendStatus(404);
                }
                res.end(err);
            }
            var range = req.headers.range;
            if (!range) {
                // 416 Wrong range
                return res.sendStatus(416);
            }
            var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
            var total = stats.size;
            var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
            var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
            res.writeHead(206, {
                "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
                "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                "Content-Length": chunksize,
                "Content-Type": mediaObject.file.mimetype
            });

            var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {start: start, end: end})
                .on("open", function () {
                    stream.pipe(res);
                }).on("error", function (err) {
                    res.end(err);
                });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.status(500).send('Missing resource token!');
    }
});
```

Now to download a simple document i have the follow html tag:

```
<a target="_self" href="http://localhost:433/resource?resourceToken=token" class="btn btn-default">                               <i class="fa fa-download"> </i></a>
```

Now when i press the button it correctly calls the method however the `header` `range` is undefined.

which means it sends the error code `416` (as shown in the above code).

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what im missing?

Comment: the range header is available only when the clients sends it, mostly when it does stream the file (video/audio player). Not when it downloads it. Unless it tries to resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range requests serve a rather specific purpose (like enabling partial downloads during audio/video scrubbing).

Your HTML suggests that you just want to present a download link for a particular resource, and the browser won't issue a range request for that (*or* it might, but only after the initial request).

So your code should allow for the `Range` header to not exist.